# [Big picture]confuse about column space and left nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

From the textbook, I found the below picture, but I'm bit confused why column space connects to left nullspace($N(A^T)$) but not nullspace($N(A)$). Can they switch positions? Why and why cannot?

[image]